# Match only dates above 2010 with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that look like this:

`"path/32632/SMCS1_20201103_051803_095_D.tif"`

And `20200103` is the part that I want to match. Now I only want to match it, if the date is after 2010. So I thought about something like this:

`.*_(201\d{5})_.*`

But this apparently does not work, and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think your subpattern `201\d{5}` *wouldn't* match date strings from `2010`? As you may have come to learn, RegExp is great at matching string patterns, but isn't well-suited for anything even close to resembling arithmetic comparisons/operations.

Comment: Additionally: "it doesn't work" isn't a particularly helpful problem statement - instead, explain *how* it doesn't work by sharing an explanation of expected vs. actual behaviors, along with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When you say *I only want to match it, if the date is after 2010.* does that mean 2010 should or should not match?

Comment: yeah this question wasn't really good... But thanks!,  I could solve it with your answer @dawg. I just didn't know why I did not match any 8 digits in a row with this regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 _20[12]\d\d{4}_
```

If you want to work after 2030 etc:

```
_20[1-9]\d\d{4}_
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YAVhuO/1)